# How to slice html into dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, beautifulsoup

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re
import pandas as pd
import os
soup_level1=BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

After importing some HTML (e.g. http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/18886/scorecard/1157372/), I've realised that what should be a table', isn't actually a table and therefore it seems I need to built the table back myself.

```
Batsmen = soup_level1.find_all('div',class_="cell batsmen")
pd.Series(Batsmen)

0     <div class="cell batsmen" data-reactid="182">B...
1     <div class="cell batsmen" data-reactid="191"><...
...
18    <div class="cell batsmen" data-reactid="541"><...
dtype: object
```

I can extract the Batsman's name using:

```
FirstBat = Batsmen[1]
FirstBat = str(FirstBat)
FirstBat = pd.Series(FirstBat)
FirstBat = FirstBat.str.split(pat = ">",expand=True)
FirstBat = FirstBat[2]
FirstBat

0    S Dhawan</a
Name: 2, dtype: object
```

I then want to be able to join the batsman's name to his stats, but Stats[0:4] refer to the headings, and Stats[5:10] refer to the first batsmen:

```
Stats = soup_level1.find_all('div',class_="cell runs")
pd.Series(Stats)
0     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="184">R</div>
1     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="185">B</div>
2     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="186">4s</...
3     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="187">6s</...
4     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="188">SR</...
5     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="194">4</div>
6     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="195">8</div>
7     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="196">1</div>
8     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="197">0</div>
9     <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="198">50.0... 
...
94    <div class="cell runs" data-reactid="548">-</div>
Length: 95, dtype: object
```

What is the best approach to be able to extra something that looks like this?

```
    Batsmen  R  B  4s  6s    SR
0  S Dhawan  4  8   0   0  50.0
```

Comment: Can you link to the website? Also, surely bs4 can extract the text from the tags for you, so `soup_level1.find_all('div',class_="cell runs")` might have a method or property on it to get just the contents without the tags.

Comment: @Dan Thanks Dan, here is an example: http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/18886/scorecard/1157372/

Comment: Looking at the first page of the docs, something like `for div in soup_level1.find_all('div',class_="cell runs"):
    print(div.string)`

Comment: Ah thanks! That's it. I should be able to manipulate it from there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something to get you started:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import numpy as np
import requests

html_doc= requests.get(r'http://www.espncricinfo.com/series/18886/scorecard/1157372/').content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, 'html.parser')

data = []
for div in soup.find_all('div',class_="cell runs"):
    data.append(div.text)

np.array(data).reshape(-1,5)
```

Which outputs

```
array([['R', 'B', '4s', '6s', 'SR'],
       ['14', '12', '2', '0', '116.66'],
       ['68', '55', '5', '1', '123.63'],
       ['39', '30', '2', '2', '130.00'],
       ['2', '3', '0', '0', '66.66'],
       ['9', '6', '1', '0', '150.00'],
       ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0.00'],
       ['0', '2', '0', '0', '0.00'],
       ['1', '2', '0', '0', '50.00'],
       ['0', '1', '0', '0', '0.00'],
       ['17', '8', '2', '1', '212.50'],
       ['R', 'B', '4s', '6s', 'SR'],
       ['0', '3', '0', '0', '0.00'],
       ['4', '2', '1', '0', '200.00'],
       ['14', '15', '2', '0', '93.33'],
       ['2', '7', '0', '0', '28.57'],
       ['0', '2', '0', '0', '0.00'],
       ['1', '3', '0', '0', '33.33'],
       ['19', '23', '2', '0', '82.60'],
       ['34', '29', '6', '0', '117.24'],
       ['3', '7', '0', '0', '42.85'],
       ['6', '3', '1', '0', '200.00'],
       ['2', '7', '0', '0', '28.57']], dtype='<U6')
```

And from there it's really not too hard to get this into a data frame. You will have to be careful though as this is reading more than one table, you can see a second 'header' row (i.e. `['R', 'B', '4s', '6s', 'SR']`) half way through so you need to decide what to do about that.

Comment: Thanks Dan! That's perfect. It pulls both scorecards but I can sort that. Cheers!